# SQL Triggers in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table that has `operation` and `status` as two columns. I want to set up a trigger so that whenever the `operation` is updated and the current status is in a list of values, **UPDATE** the `status` with the `operation` value.

Here is what I have come up with so far:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATE_STATUS_FROM_OPS]
   ON  [dbo].[TICKET]
   FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF UPDATE([operation]) AND 
    (SELECT [status] FROM [dbo].[TICKET]) in 
    ('open','closed', 'in progress')
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[TICKET]
        SET [status]=[operation]
    END

END
GO
```

This is not working at all. What did I miss?

Comment: Triggers are **highly vendor-specific** - so please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A for update trigger happens after the update. You have access to the special table Inserted which has access to all the updated values and also the Deleted table which has all the old values:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[UPDATE_STATUS_FROM_OPS]
   ON  [dbo].[TICKET]
    FOR UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    UPDATE Ticket
        SET [Status] = i.Operation
    FROM ticket
    INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON ticket.id = i.id
    WHERE i.[Status] IN  ('open','closed', 'in progress')
END
```